# Typescript define type for object will loose static object key (property) suggestion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

### Here is the code:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  [key: string]: any
}

export const button: ButtonProps = {
  primary: {
    background: theme.background.primary,
    color: theme.color.base,
  },
  base: {
    background: theme.background.base,
    color: theme.color.primary,
  },
}

// button.pr.. 
//  When I press primary, the vscode static suggestion won't show `primary` or `base` keys, because [key: string] could be any string.
```

Not expected:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhbQB.png)

Expected:
[Screenshot -  expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHt7j.png)

### Expected Behavior:

Suggestion or static type check for any properties that types defined also manually added keys.

like:

```
interface ButtonProps {
 primary: ...,
 [key: string]: ...
}
const button: ButtonProps = {
 secondary: ...
}

button.primary // ✅
button.secondary // ✅
button.third // Okay, but no suggestion.
```

Comment: There is no suggestions because of `[key: string]`

Comment: `ButtonProps` is defined as `{ [key: string]: any }`, it means that the keys can be any string, so you can't expect the static compiler to suggest you something. I suggest you to better design `ButtonProps` with a stricter type, the actual type is rather useless.

Comment: So how can I have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ran into a similar situation myself recently. The issue is that you want to get the narrow type of the object your defining while ensuring it extends the broader type. To fix this, you can create a function that just returns its input but infers it's type.

```
interface ButtonProps {
  primary: {background:string, color:string};
  [key: string]: any;
}

const createButtonProps = <T extends ButtonProps>(props: T) => props;

export const button = createButtonProps({
  primary: {                               // primary is required
    background: theme.background.primary,
    color: theme.color.base,
  },
  base: {
    background: theme.background.base,
    color: theme.color.primary,
  },
});

// You'll now see intellisense for button.primary & button.base
```

As a bonus, if you ever need to get the exact value types in the object as well, which was the case for me, you can add `as const` to the end of the object you pass to the function.